# Activity is empty when called from Nav Drawer. But button shows populated activity

Tags: android-activity, navigation-drawer

I have a Nav Drawer class that most of my activities inherit from. I have a `CurrentProjectsActivity` that I can access from my dashboard page with a button. It will show me all the projects just fine. However, when I try to start this activity from the `NavDrawer.class` I get a blank activity. What could be the problem?
This is my code:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        Intent intent;

        user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

       if (id == R.id.nav_currentProjects) {
             intent = new Intent(this, CurrentProjectsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        \\other item handlers here

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_Layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

Other activities start up just fine and everything is populated if they are called from the `NavDrawer` class. Can't figure out what the issue is with this one

Answer (score 0):

Oops. Cleaning and Rebuild did the job